# Sort set of string elements in descending order using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to sort set of string elements in descending order but the result surprises me. I can see `7.1.1` comes before `7.10.1`, not sure why.

```
$ cat sort.sh 
#!/bin/bash
for i in $( echo "5.2.0 5.1.2 7.1.1 7.10.1" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -r )
do
  echo $i
done
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./sort.sh 
7.1.1
7.10.1
5.2.0
5.1.2
```

**Expected output:**

```
$ ./sort.sh 
7.10.1
7.1.1
5.2.0
5.1.2
```

Am i missing anything here? Any tips would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Look at an ASCII table and where . and 0 are in it.

Comment: I think you want `sort -rn`

Answer (score 2):

Sort uses the sorting rules specified by the current locale. See ["Sort does not sort in normal order!"](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#Sort-does-not-sort-in-normal-order_0021) in GNU Coreutils FAQ. GNU `sort (1)` manual page contains this warning:

> *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.

If you specifically want to [sort version numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Version-sort-overview.html), see the `-V` command line option in GNU sort:

> -V, --version-sort
>
> natural sort of (version) numbers within text